# Error in parsing tweet data to csv in Python

Tags: python, json, csv, twitter, tweepy

I am currently working on a project where I want to extract the tweet text and the time of creation and put this data in a csv file. The files I am analysing are large text files (~800MB-1.5GB) containing JSON data. I have used the below program to get this data. I have piped the output of this into a text file.

```
import tweepy as tp
import sys
import pandas as pd


#Variables that contains the user credentials to access Twitter API
access_token = "..."
access_token_secret = "..."
consumer_key = "..."
consumer_secret = "..."

tweets_data = []
#This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to stdout.
class StdOutListener(tp.StreamListener):

  def on_data(self, data):
    print (data)

    return True



  def on_error(self, status):
    print (status)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    #This handles Twitter authentication and the connection to Twitter   Streaming API
    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = tp.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    stream = tp.Stream(auth, l)

    stream.filter(track=['Manchester United'])
```

EDIT: Here is a sample output of the above program.

```
{"created_at":"Mon Feb 09 07:58:51 +0000 2015","id":564694906233307137,"id_str":"564694906233307137","text":"RT @ManUtd: Take an alternative look at United's starting line-up today, courtesy of #MUTV. #mufclive\nhttps:\/\/t.co\/m1n1JkgRYq","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for iPhone\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":306297595,"id_str":"306297595","name":"Agus Wiratama","screen_name":"KunirKm","location":"Bali","url":null,"description":"girls that are uniqe and beautiful in their own way|| #GGMU #Libra #IG : @Kunirkm","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":176,"friends_count":102,"listed_count":1,"favourites_count":39,"statuses_count":4810,"created_at":"Fri May 27 16:45:02 +0000 2011","utc_offset":-32400,"time_zone":"Alaska","geo_enabled":true,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"022330","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme15\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme15\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"0084B4","profile_sidebar_border_color":"A8C7F7","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"C0DFEC","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/561223265025138688\/J3SFBWV4_normal.jpeg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/561223265025138688\/J3SFBWV4_normal.jpeg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/306297595\/1400412027","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweeted_status":{"created_at":"Sun Feb 08 15:52:42 +0000 2015","id":564451764460474369,"id_str":"564451764460474369","text":"Take an alternative look at United's starting line-up today, courtesy of #MUTV. #mufclive\nhttps:\/\/t.co\/m1n1JkgRYq","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter Web Client\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":558797310,"id_str":"558797310","name":"Manchester United","screen_name":"ManUtd","location":"#mufc","url":"http:\/\/www.manutd.com","description":"Official Twitter of Manchester United FC","protected":false,"verified":true,"followers_count":4388116,"friends_count":84,"listed_count":12006,"favourites_count":0,"statuses_count":11840,"created_at":"Fri Apr 20 15:17:43 +0000 2012","utc_offset":0,"time_zone":"Casablanca","geo_enabled":false,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"000000","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/491881264232677376\/VcPcDO7o.jpeg","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/491881264232677376\/VcPcDO7o.jpeg","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"B30000","profile_sidebar_border_color":"FFFFFF","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"EFEFEF","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/563854496074194947\/p74gErkN_normal.png","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/563854496074194947\/p74gErkN_normal.png","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/558797310\/1423268331","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweet_count":1338,"favorite_count":752,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"MUTV","indices":[73,78]},{"text":"mufclive","indices":[80,89]}],"trends":[],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/m1n1JkgRYq","expanded_url":"https:\/\/amp.twimg.com\/v\/c79db33a-7fa9-4993-be9d-12990ee17b6b","display_url":"amp.twimg.com\/v\/c79db33a-7fa\u2026","indices":[90,113]}],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en"},"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":
```

I have then tried to read this file to extract the information I need using this program.

```
import simplejson as json
from pandas import DataFrame as df
import time

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tweets_data_path = '/input.txt' #Input file path
    tweets_data = []
    tweets_file = open(tweets_data_path, "r")
    tweets = df()
    tweets1 = df()
    i=0
    for line in tweets_file:
        try:
            tweet = json.loads(line)
            tweets_data.append(tweet)
            i+=1
            print(i)
            if i > 10000:
                i=0
                tweets['CreatedAt'] = [tweet["created_at"] for tweet in tweets_data]
                tweets['text'] = [tweet["text"] for tweet in tweets_data]
                print(tweets_data)
                timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
                filename = 'Out' + timestr + '.csv'
                print(filename)
                tweets.to_csv(filename, index=True)
                tweets_data.clear()
                tweets.drop()
                print(tweets)

            #print('Here I am')
        except:
            continue

    try:
        #Creating a new data frame as the old one creates a conflict with the size of the index
        tweets1['CreatedAt'] = [tweet["created_at"] for tweet in tweets_data]
        tweets1['text'] = [tweet["text"] for tweet in tweets_data]
        timestr1 = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
        filename1 = 'Out' + timestr1 + '.csv'
        tweets1.to_csv(filename, index= True)
    except:
        print('Excepti')
```

The problem is that I am not able to save more than one csv file while the code continues to run for the entire length of the JSON file. Have I made an error in the looping or managing the exceptions? 
I am pretty new to Python and programming in general. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Since I don't have the credentials, it's a bit hard for me to reproduce. Can you at least paste some of the output from the first program?

Comment: Add the output to the question.

Comment: Well, you have posted just one line, and it's not complete. I'm assuming you actually have many lines and that the file you managed to create is created correctly. In that case, maybe the problem is the name of the file, which only change after a whole second (a second is a lot for a computer). Add a `filename = str(i) + filename` or something like that, and try again.

Comment: No I don't think the problem is with the file name. I can see the numbers (i) printed in the console and this runs for about 30 seconds before starting from 0 again. So I don't think that is the problem. But I'll try to do something and change that.

Comment: ok i tried replacing the file name with a string containing another count variable with the file name. 
filename = str(j) + 'out' + '.csv'. It still does not work, I am also getting an exception printed at the end. Could this mean something?